# Moq multi-interface question

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

This may or may not be a multi-interface problem, but I'm doing something like this:

```
var mockInterface1 = new Mock<IInterface1>();
var mockInterface2 = mockInterface1.As<IInterface2>();
mockInterface1.Expect( foo => foo.Foo(It.IsAny<IInterface3>() ) );

...

otherObject.DoSomething( (IInterface1)mockInterface2.Object );
```

On the DoSomething line at runtime I get:

MyTest (TestFixtureSetUp):
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'IInterface1Proxy184f83d417624e05b450fa40c2c5d35c' threw an exception.

----> System.BadImageFormatException : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Does this have something to do with my not having the right Expect code, or is it related to the multiple interfaces in my mock, or something else?

Comment: This works as of Moq 3.1.416.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this link:
[Castle Project Topic](http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?p=14322&sid=6327e0e0b3a61cff948bf2d35a9e923d)

which seems to indicate that its a problem in Castle's DynamicProxy, which is used by Moq (and RhinoMocks).

Comment: I get this as well when using Moq 3.0.308.2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer as such, but it does sound like a bug in MOQ.  What version are you using?  I just tried your example with 2.6 (2.6.1014.1) and I don't get an exception.

Comment: I'm using 2.6 (don't know the exact version, but libs say 2.6)

Comment: Just checked again: 2.6.1014.1