# Why does getting the mocked instance created with Moq throw a System.BadImageFormatException?

Tags: debugging, moq, reflection.emit, castle-dynamicproxy

This question may be related to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305345/moq-multi-interface-question) question and it certainly results with a System.BadImageFormatException. Maybe it's the same thing but exposed differently?

I have the following the code:

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : class, new() {
  T FooMethod(object o);
}

public interface IFooRepo {
  F GetFoo<T, F>() where T : class, new() where F : IFoo<T>;
}
```

Then I have a test that mocks IFooRepo using Moq like so:

```
var instance = new Mock<IFooRepo>().Object;
```

The above code runs fine except when debugging the test with Visual Studio 2008. When I step over the above line a System.BadImageFormatException is thrown from System.Reflection.Emit via Castle.DynamicProxy. Could this be similar to [something](http://groups.google.com/group/RhinoMocks/msg/500daa19f20c9748) Ayende Rahien posted?

Now the workaround is to implement a fake for IFooRepo but I'm curious as to why a bad image is generated for this kind of scenario and is there a fix? Is System.Reflection.Emit buggy? Or am I missing something obvious in my own code?

**EDIT**: Posted the incorrect signature for GetFoo(). Corrected the signature to GetFoo<T, F>(), which correctly reproduces the problem. With the GDR installed this problem persists.

**EDIT**: It seems that if the constraint on F includes type parameter T BadImageFormatException is raised. But I change it to, say `where F : class, new()`, then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I agree that Ayende's post explains this behavior, and that it only happens when constraints on one generic parameter reference another.  I encounter it, too, with the GDR, and have adopted the same workaround of hand-coded fakes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [install the .NET 3.5 SP1 GDR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NET35SP1GDRIsAvailableToDownload.aspx)? [its a know issue](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/13/How-.Net-3.5-SP1-broke-Rhino-Mocks.aspx)

Comment: I have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed. No idea if the GDR is installed though. How can I tell? And how did you make the connection between Ayende's post and the GDR download page? I'd seen Ayende's post before posting my question but saw no reference to the GDR. Oh and thanks for the link BTW, I'll check it out soon.

Comment: Scott Hanselman comments near the bottom of the page of how to determine if the GDR is installed. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NET35SP1GDRIsAvailableToDownload.aspx

Comment: The GDR was already applied in my case. Then I discovered that I posted the incorrect code snippets. I've corrected the snippets in the question.